# documentdb - slow performance on large return result on .net query sdk

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am working on documentdb which using the following code

```
    var ee =client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collection.SelfLink, querySpec)
```

I am facing performance issue when i execute

```
    ee.ToList();
```

It take around 1+ minute to complete a 700+ records. (if the return results is more, it will take more longer time to complete the action)
If I try my query on the Azure Query Explore, it just take few seconds.

Is there anything I can do to optimize the code? Or is there anyway I can get the return result as JSON string.

Thanks.

Comment: I too am having awful performance returning a "large" result set from DocumentDB. It's gotten worse with the latest version of the SDK that introduced partitioning. This "large" result set of mine wouldn't cause SQL Server or Azure Table Storage to even blink, but I'm getting query times of over 3 minutes in DocumentDB. Very frustrating.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try increasing the maxItemCount to -1 (max) and see if that effects performance:

```
var ee =client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collection.SelfLink, querySpec, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
```

Note, this still won't be as fast as it runs on the query explorer for two reasons:

1. The query explorer returns as soon as it fetches one page. By specifying `ToList()`, you are waiting until all return. The query explorer defaults to 100 rather than -1 so it'll come back quicker. For fair comparison, increase the items per page setting for your query explorer case. You may want to consider a paging approach (with a smaller page size) for your application to partially render the initial page and make it appear more performant.
2. Others have reported and I personally have experienced a large latency per round trip when crossing the azure data center boundary. When calling from a node.js server in the same data center, I get sub 10ms latency. When using the same code running locally, it's a minimum of 250ms. My measured ping latency is 26ms, so I assume the latency is added at the data center boundary, not my network. You may want to consider running your code in the same data center as your DocumentDB.

As for returning as a JSON string, here are 2.5 options:

1. You might want to look at node.js (or edge.js running in .NET, that's the additional 1/2). It's native JavaScript rather than C# so it's closer in concept to DocumentDB. The .NET API for DocumentDB suffers from paradigm differences/translation. Note, I've used edge.js to run node.js inside of .NET. Crazy but it works. Then you can use the DocumentDB node.js library instead of the DocumentDB .NET library. This gives you more control.
2. If you want to stay pure .NET, you could directly hit the DocumentDB REST API using a package like [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/).

Comment: Regarding `maxItemCount`, you can now set to `-1` to remove the page size limit (# of documents). You don't have to live with just `1000`. **Note:** The query response is still be bounded by response size limit (# of bytes over the wire). Use projections (`SELECT` clause) to reduce the # of bytes coming across the wire.

Comment: @aliuy, nice!!! Neither the node.js nor the server-side docs show that change. Is that pending or should I submit a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out. The reason I didn't specific the maxItemCount is because I need to get the all the records and which later I will use to generate the graph and grid binding.

Comment: ToList()  causes it to fetch all pages before returning regardless of the page size. Smaller page sizes means more round trips which takes longer.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone We introduced `-1` page size just two days ago (9/29)... Sounds like we may have missed some docs. I'd love it if you could point out which docs, or send us a PR :)

Comment: @Teo, curious about how this turned out for you. I see that you accepted the answer. I'm guessing that the performance is now acceptable? How close to the Query Explorer did it end up?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone sorry for the late reply. The problem is actually caused by request unit. I had change from s1 to s3 and the performance increase a lot. But it end up with more expansive costing. Now try to implement documentdb-lumenize aggregate function with .net sdk but still no luck. 
Anyway thanks for your help.